# Gedit: function, array, object, ... block wrapping

Tags: text-editor, gedit, gedit-plugin

Is there any plugin for the Gedit text editor that enables wrapping of blocks of codes (like functions, loops, conditions, arrays, ...) inside a bordered or colored are? as in kate for example.

Here is a scrennshot of what I want (note that this wrapping is created by another plugin: code completion)

[Please open the image in a new tab/window to see it]

[image: Please open the image in a new tab/window to see it]